# How can I activity close in Android?

Tags: android

I have three `classActivity` created. One is super class and other sub class and third is HomeActivity.

Code for super class is :

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {

     Button btnHome = null;

     @Override
     protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     }

     public void onHomeClick(View view) {
         String LOG_TAG = "Akshar";
         System.out.println("Hello11111");
         btnHome = (Button) view;
         Log.v(LOG_TAG, "index=" + btnHome);
     } 
   }
```

and my subclass code  is :

```
public class ChooseIsland extends MyActivity {

     Button btn_home = null;
     MyActivity ob1 = new MyActivity();

     @Override
     public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
         setContentView(R.layout.chooseiland);
         addListenerOnButton();
     }

     private void addListenerOnButton() {
         // TODO Auto-generated method stub
         ob1.onHomeClick(btn_home);
     }
 }
```

Now I want to go on Home page when click so when I write ?

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, HomeActivity.class);
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no close operation as such in android. You should make sure you do not save anything in stack so whenever you are traversing from one activity to other, make sure you use intent flags to clear history or top of stack and then call finish.

Answer (score 0):

finish() will close the current activity and the previous activity will come to foreground.

Answer (score 0):

Generally to we  write finish() method to close activity.